# Ubuntu Button Click Authentication

Tags: unity, sudo, permissions

After upgrading from Windows to Ubuntu, I really like the operating system.
The only point I find that is missing is the Windows functionnality to authenticate administrator permissions only by clicking a button (since the user is already logged in).
I would find this a lot easier instead of having to type my password countless times per day.

Is it possible to configure Ubuntu in a similar way?

http://www.bu.edu/tech/files/2012/02/WindowsUAC_Adobe.gif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regards to running Ubuntu as root, or creating "Authentication" this might be a feature that could be added, but doesn't seem like a safe thing to do.

There are some thoughts on the subject of running Ubuntu as root that can be found [here.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo)

Does this answer your question?

Comment: I don't understand what kind of security risk this could impose since the user already authenticated once in his account and he is using the confirm button to grant access thereafter. I will take a look at the link you provided, thanks!

Comment: Well. Running as root is generally not advised as it is a good way to break stuff. Inside of the reading that I linked is an [(example here)](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1877557) with a scenario in which a new user "borked" their system. It's just a preventive measure in regards to security and user error.

Comment: @Daniel because anyone can sit down and "click the button", which means someone might be able to hack a remote button click, very serious security risk, and for linux this then would mean the password would need to be stored somewhere to pass to the system on the button click

Comment: @Daniel also consider you had this setup and I wanted to get a virus to install(online not in person) In the normal setup, my virus would have a hard time installing as it couldn't get past the password needed by `sudo`.  but with you system I would only need to set up the virus to simulate the button input, then it would have full access to install in any folder on your system.  The default set-up is why Linux is inherently more secure than Windows, Windows makes admin. access inherently easy while Linux makes it inherently difficult to an outside(remote) program.